# Why is rails designed to need respond_with in actions to support multiple formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a controller that supports multiple formats, it seems that a respond_with or respond_to block is needed.

Why isn't the default behavior to look for an action_name.format.erb file, and if that doesn't exist to look for a to_format method?

It seems like it's a violation of DRY to have controller actions sprinkled with respond_with and respond_to.  The rails designer generally make good design decisions, however, so I'm curious what I'm missing that makes this design decision a good idea.

Obviously Rails would need to know which formats to respond to, but this can be specified with the controller-level respond_to statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's could be many formates (html, json, xml, txt, png, mp3, javascript and etc.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type 
To find needed format could take much time it decreases response time of all application.
Thus we restrict possible formats manually with `respond_to` or `respond_with`

Comment: Sure, a controller-level respond_to is needed (I updated the question -- thanks), but why have action-level respond_width as well?